# Saving data for related Tables with foreign key - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having trouble saving my entities to the database using EntityFramework. I have to tables, Player and Address. The Player table has a reference to the Address table by means of an AddressId foreign key relationship. So Player.AddressId points to Address.AddressId.

Now when calling the following code, I get an error that says: "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a storage-generated column"

```
public override int CreatePlayer(BizObjects.Player player)
{
    var entity = new EntityFramework.Player();

    entity.PlayerId = player.PlayerId;
    entity.FirstName = player.FirstName;
    entity.LastName = player.LastName;
    entity.Gender = player.Gender;
    entity.BirthDate = player.BirthDate;
    entity.DisplayAge = player.DisplayAge;
    entity.Level = player.Level;
    entity.PlayingHand = player.PlayingHand;
    entity.BackhandType = player.BackhandType;
    entity.PlayingStyle = player.PlayingStyle;
    entity.Description = player.Description;
    entity.UserId = player.UserId;
    entity.Address = new Address();
    entity.Address.AddressId = player.Address.AddressId;
    entity.Address.Line1 = player.Address.Line1;
    entity.Address.Line2 = player.Address.Line2;
    entity.Address.City = player.Address.City;
    entity.Address.State = player.Address.State;
    entity.Address.ZipCode = player.Address.ZipCode;

    _entities.AddToPlayer(entity);
    _entities.SaveChanges();

    return entity.PlayerId;
}
```

I am new to using EF. Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: Is the value of Player.Address.AddressId greater than zero? 
and Is Address.AddressId an integer based IDENTITY column?

Comment: Address.AddressId is an integer identity column autoincremented. In the code implementation presented Player.Address.AddressId is null since an Address has not been created yet.

Comment: I guess I am not sure if by creating the Player entity the Address entity will be created as well since both tables are related. I would like to know what the best way would be about saving related tables using EF.

Comment: Ok so on what line does the exception get thrown?

Comment: And what is the Player.UserId property? Is this a foreign key of some sort?

Comment: The call that throws the error is _entities.SaveChanges();

Player.UserId is a foreign key to the Membership table that records the user in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using EF 1.0?

Mapping entity properties to FK columns in EF 1.0 is not supported, you have to use a relationship and navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and set 'Identity Specification' to 'No'.
After an update of my EDMX the problem went away.